# opencv load and display image

Tags: c++, opencv

I have installed  opencv 3.0 and verified that its properly working.Then started a tutorial on Loading and displaying an image which gave me errors  stating that 
‘CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR’ was not declared in this scope.I went through similar posts but were not helpful

and here is the code.Any help is very much appreciated.

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    if( argc != 2)
    {
     cout <<" Usage: display_image ImageToLoadAndDisplay" << endl;
     return -1;
    }

    Mat image;
    image = imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);   // Read the file

    if(! image.data )                              // Check for invalid input
    {
        cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
        return -1;
    }

    namedWindow( "Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );// Create a window for display.
    imshow( "Display window", image );                   // Show our image inside it.

    waitKey(0);                                          // Wait for a keystroke in the window
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: flags were changed to [IMREAD_COLOR, etc.](http://docs.opencv.org/ref/master/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#gga61d9b0126a3e57d9277ac48327799c80af660544735200cbe942eea09232eb822)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation for OpenCV 3.0 can be found here: http://docs.opencv.org/3.0.0/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html

The current enum responsible for imread is:

```
enum    cv::ImreadModes {
  cv::IMREAD_UNCHANGED = -1,
  cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE = 0,
  cv::IMREAD_COLOR = 1,
  cv::IMREAD_ANYDEPTH = 2,
  cv::IMREAD_ANYCOLOR = 4,
  cv::IMREAD_LOAD_GDAL = 8
}
```

This means you need to use `cv::IMREAD_COLOR` when using OpenCv 3.0 instead of `cv::CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR`.

```
image = imread(argv[1], IMREAD_COLOR);   // Read the file
```

Answer (score 0):

CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR is declared in opencv2/imgcodecs/imgcodecs_c.h.
Therefore, you need to add

```
#include<opencv2/imgcodecs/imgcodecs_c.h>
```

Besides, you can include just one header file

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
```

instead of separately include all the header files in opencv.